# SQL delete elements with a relation table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, relationship, sql-delete

I have two tables one relationship table.
Something like that:

```
table1 (id PRIMARY KEY, ...)
table2 (id PRIMARY KEY, ...)
rel_table (id_table1 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES table1(id), id_table2 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES table2(id))
```

The tables are not created by me and I cannot modify their definition.

I want to remove the items from table1 that meet a certain condition, and I also want to remove the items from table2 and rel_table that relate them

something similar to the following

```
begin;

delete t2, rel
from table2 t2
inner join rel_table rel on rel.id_table2 = t2.id
where rel.id_table1 in (...);

delete from table1 where id in (...);

commit;
```

But I'm using postgresql and this doesn't seem possible.
What would be the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can do this:

Lets say this is your table1:

```
create table table1 (id int primary key)--if it is not primary key, add it
```

And it's data:

```
insert into table1 values(1)
insert into table1 values(2)
insert into table1 values(3)
```

Lets say this is your table2:

```
create table table2 (id int)
```

And it's data:

```
insert into table2 values(1)
insert into table2 values(2)
```

Lets say this is your rel_table:

```
create table rel_table (id_1 int, id_2 int)
```

And it's data:

```
insert into rel_table values(1, 1)
insert into rel_table values(1, 2)
insert into rel_table values(2, 2)
```

If you select the data like this:

```
select * from table1
select * from table2
select * from rel_table
```

You will see all the data

But then if you add this:

```
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES table1(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE rel_table ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_1) 
REFERENCES table1(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

And then delete one data from table1:

```
delete from table1
where id = 1
```

Now when you select the data from all 3 tables you will see the data related to the deleted row from table1 is missing in every table...

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d88be1c73599b951b40015e205798181)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the tables are not created by me and I cannot modify their definition. But I understand your idea

Comment: You are welcome, that is why I started with "I am not sure if you can do this".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is something you can use because for both tables table1 and table2 you will need to say what is the id value you need to delete.

```
WITH 
  a AS 
  ( DELETE FROM table1
    WHERE id = 1
    RETURNING id
  ),
  b AS
  ( DELETE FROM table2 
    WHERE id = 1
    RETURNING id 
  ),
  c AS
  ( DELETE FROM rel_table
    WHERE rel_table.id_1 IN (SELECT table1.id FROM table1)
    or rel_table.id_2 IN (SELECT table2.id FROM table2)
    RETURNING rel_table.id_1, rel_table.id_2
  )
SELECT
    a.id,
    b.id,
    c.id_1, 
    c.id_2
FROM a
  LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
  LEFT JOIN c ON c.id_1 = a.id and c.id_2 = b.id
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a8415cdacadbc800231befd573605c53)